# Hibernate 6.2.6.Final QueryException when using enum in max function

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-6.x

I have migrated from Hibernate 6.1.7.Final to 6.2.6.Final (bug exists also in 6.2.0.Final) and there are some enum related issues.
I have a query as below, that was working in older version, but it is failing now:

```sql
select datasourceView.id, max(datasourceView.datasourceStatus) as DATASOURCE_STATUS_helper_column, datasourceView.id as ID_helper_column
```

The error is:

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Parameter 1 of function max() has type COMPARABLE, but argument is of type com.xxx.datasource.domain.DatasourceStatus`

Enum mapping:

```java
@Column(name = "status")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) 
private DatasourceStatus datasourceStatus;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by switching from the @Enumerated to the [@Converter](https://to%20https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/) and creating a converter for enums.